# Unable to override default Visual Studio Code settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently in the Visual Studio Code Output window I've noticed message:

> For C++ source files, the cppStandard was changed from "c++17" to "".

I've tried fixing that by adding a line **"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17"** in following files:

- Folder Settings JSON
- Workspace Settings JSON
- User Settings JSON

I've accessed these files by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + P and selecting to edit the JSON of those files, i.e. "Preferences: Open User/Workspace/Folder Settings (JSON)

After restarting Visual Studio Code I still get the same message, as shown below.

It seems to me like this is a new bug in Visual Studio Code as previously everything was working fine, and I had those settings set.

[image]

I'm using the ms-vscode.cpptools extension, version 1.18.5

These are the contents of my c_cpp_properties.json files in .vscode dir:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Linux",
      "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"]
    }],
    "version": 4
}
```

VS Code info:

```
Version: 1.84.1
Commit: 2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f
Date: 2023-11-06T12:35:31.181Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.8.0-43-generic
```

Comment: please edit your question to answer the following: 1) did you create a [`./.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) in your workspace? if so, show its contents. 2) what is the version number of your C/C++ extension? 3) have you touched the configuration provider setting? / does this issue ticket https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11574 match your problem?

Comment: The answer is no, the issue described in that ticket does not match my problem.
I'm able to define configurationProvider and it remains saved.

Comment: then I'd suggest that you also raise an issue ticket in the cpptools repo. If you do, please edit the link to your issue ticket into your question post. (and please provide as much detail as you can in your issue ticket. don't be lazy and just link to this question post in your issue ticket).